# Pandas eval - call user defined function on columns

Tags: python, pandas, eval

As my question states, I would like to invoke custom function on run-time to a dataframe. Use of custom function will be to calculate difference between two date (i.e. age), convert year to months, find max-min from two columns etc.

So Far, I succeeded in performing arithmetic operations and few functions like abs(), sqrt() but couldn't get min()-max() working.Things working are,

```
df.eval('TT = sqrt(Q1)',inplace=True)
df.eval('TT1 = abs(Q1-Q2)',inplace=True)
df.eval('TT2 = (Q1+Q2)*Q3',inplace=True)
```

Following code works with eval. How can I use the same with dataframe eval ?

```
def find_max(x,y):
    return np.maximum(x,y)

eval('max1')(4,7)

def find_age(date_col1,date_col2):
    return 'I know how to calc age but how to call func this with df.eval and assign to new col'
```

Sample dataframe:

```
op_d = {'ID': [1, 2,3],'V':['F','G','H'],'AAA':[0,1,1],'D':['2019/12/04','2019/02/01','2019/01/01'],'DD':['2019-12-01','2016-05-31','2015-02-15'],'CurrentRate':[7.5,2,2],'NoteRate':[2,3,3],'BBB':[0,4,4],'Q1':[2,8,10],'Q2':[3,5,7],'Q3':[5,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
```

Any help or link to Doc is appreciated.

helpful links I found but not addressing my issues are:

[Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval)

[Using local variables with multiple assignments with pandas eval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079201/using-local-variables-with-multiple-assignments-with-pandas-eval-function)

[Passing arguments to python eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100203/passing-arguments-to-python-eval)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions can be called as usual, you need to reference them with the `@` synbol:

```
df                                                                  
   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  0  1

def my_func(x, y): return x + y                                     

df.eval('@my_func(A, B)')                                          
0    1
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Of course, the expectation here is that your functions expect series as arguments. Otherwise, wrap your function in a call to [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), as appropriate.

Comment: If I have function as, def max1(x,y): return np.maximum(x,y) and call df.eval('@max1(TT,TT1)') , I get  ```TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed ```. Do you know why is it a case?

Comment: I guess default engine 'numexpr' can't handle it. resolved it using engine='python'.

Comment: @Prish that seems right to me. Numexpr is generally faster but there are limitations to its use.

Comment: do you know how to call round,ceil,floor function from eval? i.e. ```df.eval('round(A-B)')```. abs() and sqrt() works fine.

Comment: @Prish If you just need to round the result, doesn't `df.eval('A-B').round()` work?

Comment: Unfortunately No. It resulted in error. I am tracking this issue in a different question but thought of asking you here since no one has answer to it. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60762008/calling-round-ceiling-floor-min-max-in-pandas-eval